# Omitting comments C++

Tags: c++, comments

I had this piece of code that read another file and count the number of lines; that part is working fine.

What I'm trying to do is to omit the comment lines, so the program reads only the actual code and not the comments.

Hoping someone can help me :/

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <istream>
using namespace std;
int main() {

  int numlines = 0; 
  string line;

  ifstream myfile("wr.cpp");
  while (myfile.good ())
  {
    getline(myfile, line);
    ++numlines;  
  }
  cout << "Number of lines: "<<numlines<< endl;  
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: You will count one too many lines because you don't test that `getline()` worked. You've not tried to count comments — show us what you're trying.  There've been at least two 'detect comment' questions in the last week — see what you can find on SO that already answers your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, `while (myfile.good ())` is wrong.  It should be `while (std::getline(myfile, line))`.  Testing `good()` will only test the status of the stream *after* you've attempted to read (and already incremented your count).  Testing the `getline` call will test it immediately.

After that, you just need to check the first 2 characters to see if it is a comment line (assuming `//` and `/*` are your comment blocks and all comments are only a single line):

```
while (std::getline(myfile, line))
{
    std::string test = line.substr(0, 2);
    if (!(test == "//" || test == "/*"))
    {
        ++numlines;
    }
}
```

Comment: Depending on the application this may fail. If this code is going to be reused make sure you address the case where "/*" is spanning multiple lines of comments. As Zac said "assuming // and /* are your comment blocks and all comments are only a single line".

Comment: Thanks Wilsonator, I will take care of double line comment. This piece of code help me alot. Thanks for your comment too